# Flutter: How to set only two element in a row, rest in the new line?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So I am trying to render a list of the elements in a row, where the premise is just to render only two elements in the row and rest to render in the new line.

Following is the mock

[image: mock]

Now, the list of element i am getting from a api.

Following is my code.

```
Container _subjectwise() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      child: Row(
        children: listofsubject != null && listofsubject.length > 0
            ? listofsubject.map((item) {
                return Flexible(
                  child: Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    elevation: 3,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 3, bottom: 3, left: 0, right: 0),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 10,
                          ),
                          Image(
                              image: AssetImage("images/live.png"),
                              width: 35,
                              // height: 35,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 5,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: ListTile(
                              dense: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 0),
                              title: Text(
                                'Mental Ability',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList()
            : [],
      ),
    );
  }
```

So, is there a property or something which limits no of the element in a row ?

Thanks

Comment: You can split `listofsubject` into list of lists with 2 elements and put many `Row` with 2 widgets into `Column`

Comment: You can use `Wrap` widget.

Comment: Since you are sure it's just always the first two elements you put in a row. Just take array[0] and array[1] items and put them in a row.. create a new list  `newArr = [for(int i=2;i<arr.length;i++)CustomWidget(i)]` which you can use to populate your list view

Comment: I meant to show only two in a row not just the first two

Comment: @GauravKumar do you want to add 2 elements in a row and then the next 2 in the next row and so on? So basically a list of 2 widgets in a row?

Comment: yes exactly like that. but, considering I am having a list with unknown element. I don't know how to do that

Comment: Use Grid I would say.